# Can I specify default values for a config.yml on my java application?

Tags: java, yaml, dropwizard

I am currently working with my java application with dropwizard.

It works fine and I run it sending a yml file full or parameters.

So, for example, one of them is this one:

```
reporting:
  enabled: false
```

So, what I want to do is to make this yml file my default and when needed (for future functions) send the value of this `var`

So Id like to do something like this

```
reporting:
  enabled: ${REPORTING_FLAG:false}
```

Then I can send REPORTING_FLAG as a environment parameter (docker) and should work fine....

The issue is that I see this model is not recognised by my app.

Is there any way I can do it like this? is there an extra configuration to take in consideration? Ive done it before with a spring app but this seems to be different.

Right now I am getting an error that the expected boolean value is not valid (taking the whole line as a string)

Ideas?

Comment: Do you explicitly query `getParameter("reporting.enabled")`, or is there a binding mechanism like Spring's `@ConfigurationProperties`?

Comment: is not spring but I do have something like @Value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after reading more dropwizard documentation I found this: https://www.dropwizard.io/0.8.2/docs/manual/core.html

Environment variables

The dropwizard-configuration module also provides the capabilities to substitute configuration settings with the value of environment variables using a SubstitutingSourceProvider and EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application<MyConfiguration> {
    // [...]
    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        // Enable variable substitution with environment variables
        bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(
                new SubstitutingSourceProvider(bootstrap.getConfigurationSourceProvider(),
                                                   new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor()
                )
        );

    }

    // [...]
}
```

The configuration settings which should be substituted need to be explicitly written in the configuration file and follow the substitution rules of StrSubstitutor from the Apache Commons Lang library.

```
mySetting: ${DW_MY_SETTING}
defaultSetting: ${DW_DEFAULT_SETTING:-default value}
```