# In dropwizard configuration am I allowed to use environment variable as default?

Tags: java, dropwizard

I couldn't find any documentation for this. For example, I know this is possible:

```
defaultSetting: ${DW_DEFAULT_SETTING:-default value}
```

But what if I want logic to say if DW_DEFAULT_SETTING is not defined, then use another env variable

```
defaultSetting: ${DW_DEFAULT_SETTING:-${ANOTHER_SETTING}}
```

Is this possible? The only other alternative I can think of is defining a custom getter for defaultSetting in my Configuration class which would read system env variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it should be possible.

### How to enable it

You could use the constructor [`EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor​(boolean strict, boolean substitutionInVariables)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.dropwizard/dropwizard-project/latest/io/dropwizard/configuration/EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor.html) with the second argument as `true` to enable substitution inside variables.

For bootsrapping your app with this special `EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor​` instance, see [*WarFox*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32231630/5730279) in related question [Overriding server connector config with env variables with dropwizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464451/overriding-server-connector-config-with-env-variables-with-dropwizard/32231630#32231630).

The `SubstitutingSourceProvider` to use environment variables inside YAML files is explained here: [Can I specify default values for a config.yml on my java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831014/can-i-specify-default-values-for-a-config-yml-on-my-java-application/53832360#53832360).

### How it works

#### Dropwizard Configuration uses Apache Commons Text

Responsible for environment variable substitution is the class [`EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/release/4.0.x/dropwizard-configuration/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/configuration/EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor.java).

It is implemented by inheritance and uses Apache Commons Text:  `extends StringSubstitutor`.

#### StringSubstitutor allows recursive resolution

From [`StringSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) 's JavaDoc:

> #### Using Recursive Variable Replacement
>
> Variable replacement can work recursively by calling `setEnableSubstitutionInVariables(boolean)` with `true`. If a variable value contains a variable then that variable will also be replaced. Cyclic replacements are detected and will throw an exception.
>
> You can get the replace result to contain a variable prefix. For example:
>
> `"The variable ${${name}} must be used."`
>
> If the value of the "name" variable is "x", then only the variable "name" is replaced resulting in:
>
> `"The variable ${x} must be used."`